# How to run a notifier if connected to specific Wi-Fi?

Tags: htc-desire, cyanogenmod

Is there any way to run a [notifier](http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/) if I get connected to specified Wi-Fi? and, then get turn the notifier service off when disconnected?

---

cyanogenmod 7 + HTC Desire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need apps like Tasker or Locale to perform the sort of action you want.

Comment: yup, Tasker can definitely do this.